# How to invoke the Get() method of optional objects

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream, option-type

I have the task is to implement classes that can be used to represent points and tracks, along with a small program that demonstrates use of the classes.

In the Track class I have implemented a method that reads data from a CSV file, parses it and adds the data to an **ArrayList**: `List<Point> track = new ArrayList<> ();`

Here is the ***readFile()*** method:

```
// readFile method that creates a sequence of point objects from data in a file, the name of which is supplied as a string parameter
    public void readFile(String test) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Scanner for specified file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(test));
        int iteration = 0;
        track.clear ();

        //Fetch and parse
        while (input.hasNextLine ())  {
            String newLine = input.nextLine ();
            if (iteration == 0) { iteration++; continue;}
                String delimiter = ",";
                String[] line = newLine.split(delimiter);
            if (line.length != 4) {
                throw new GPSException ("File contains illegal number of values.");
            }
            else {
                ZonedDateTime time  = ZonedDateTime.parse (line[0]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble (line[1]);
                double latitude  = Double.parseDouble (line[2]);
                double elevation = Double.parseDouble (line[3]);

                Point newPoint = new Point (time, longitude, latitude, elevation);
                track.add (newPoint);
            }
        }
            input.close ();
        }
```

Along with various methods such as ***add()***, ***size()***, and ***get()*** (all self explanatory), I am also implementing two methods to find both the lowest and highest points. For this I'm using the **Streams API** - but the problem is that the methods *have to return Point objects*, **not** Optionals. I know that Optional objects have a ***get()*** method that returns the contained object, so using that would fix the observed problem but I do not know how to invoke this method with the code I've already written for the functions:

```
// Lowest point method
    public Optional<Point> lowestPoint() {
        return track.stream().min (Comparator.comparingDouble (Point::getElevation));
    }

    // Highest point method
    public Optional<Point> highestPoint() {
        return track.stream().max (Comparator.comparingDouble (Point::getElevation));
    }
```

I also want to add validation to both of these methods, but would appreciate any guidance on how to invoke the ***get()*** method correctly so that I can return a Point object instead of an Optional object.

I have added the validation to the methods, and it passes the provided unit tests (my lecturer provided a set of tests with the assignment). But guys, I will admit.

The validation that's being used throughout the majority of the program is one we had created for us, and it's defined as follows:

```
public class GPSException extends RuntimeException {
  public GPSException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
```

The problem is, when using either ***.get()*** or ***.else()*** to return a point object, I'm still running into all sorts of problems. I have create a new Point instance in the class, but the instance is rejected. The code is as follows:

```
// Lowest point method
    public Optional<Point> lowestPoint() {
        ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.now ();
        double longitude = 0;
        double latitude = 0;
        double elevation = 0;
        if (track.size () != 4) {
            throw new GPSException ("Not enough points to compute");
        } else {
            Point lp = new Point (time, longitude, latitude, elevation);
            return track.stream ()
                        .min (Comparator.comparingDouble (Point::getElevation))
                        .orElse (lp);
        }
    }
```

I'm struggling to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So you want e.g. `public Point lowestPoint()`? What should the result be if the `Optional<Point>` happens to be empty?

Comment: `get` is low-level. For most purposes you should prefer to use `orElse`, `orElseThrow` or some other method.

Comment: I have edited my OP in response to comments/answers. I'm having problems getting  `orElse` to work.

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, `Error:(78, 33) java: incompatible types: Point cannot be converted to java.util.Optional<Point>`

Comment: You didn't change the return type to `Point`

Comment: Ah yes, so simple...that's allowed me to return tyep Point for both lowest and highest points. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Optional::orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to return a default value:

```
public Point lowestPoint() {
    return track.stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(Point::getElevation))
                .orElse(someDefaultValue);
}
```

And likewise for `highestPoint`:

```
public Point highestPoint() {
    return track.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(Point::getElevation))
                .orElse(someDefaultValue);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my OP in response to comments/answers. I'm having problems getting `orElse` to work. Would you possibly be able to highlight what I'm doing wrong and how to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

The `Optional` [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) features a number of methods to handle the desired outcome based on what the optional holds, including:

- (as mentioned by [GBlodgett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8534008/gblodgett)) an `orElse` method that returns an alternate (typically "default") value if the optional is empty, or
- interestingly here as well - an `orElseThrow` taking a `Supplier<Throwable>` if you want to throw an exception should the `Optional` be empty,
- etc. etc.

The simplest (yet not advisable) way available to you would be of course to just chain `get` to your `min` and `max` invocations, which would either return a `Point` instance, or throw `NoSuchElementException` if the `Optional`'s empty.

The recommended practice would be to leverage the `Optional` API to handle cases where no value is returned by your `min` or `max` invocations.